# mySQL passing a variable as cells name does not results in cells content

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

To query in different cells of a given table I want to use one function where I pass the cell´s name to query, like this :

```
$cell = 'frames';

$query = $this->db->prepare('SELECT :cell FROM time_table WHERE time = :time ');
$query->bindValue(':cell', trim($cell), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':time', trim($time), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$success = $query->execute();
$query_result = $query->fetchAll();

 print_r($query_result);
```

But instead of getting the content of the `frames` I get the cell' name, which is `frames`.

What do I need to do to get the content ?

Comment: You can't use bind variables for table or column names

Comment: So I have to prepare for each column I want to query its own statement ?

Comment: You can interpolate, as long as it's whitelisted (ie you know the column exists, and it isn't based on user input (or is validated user input)

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer: It's not possible.
Placeholders can only insert *values* in the prepared statement. To workaround this issue, please use [PDO::quote](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php):

```
$cell = 'frames';

$query = $this->db->prepare('SELECT '.$this->db->quote(trim($cell)).' FROM time_table WHERE time = :time ');
$query->bindValue(':time', trim($time), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$success = $query->execute();
$query_result = $query->fetchAll();

print_r($query_result);
```

Comment: What about SQL injections ?

Comment: @Ben That's why you should use it, instead of directly injecting the value. Quote will take care of any characters that would allow an sql injection, if properly used - Please have a look at the Security Warning in the (now correctly ;-) ) linked manual!